# Interpretation of a sentence taken from REUTERS

Tags: grammar-myths

He remained one of the world's most revered public figures, combining celebrity sparkle with an unwavering message of freedom, respect and human rights.

I find it really difficult to understand "combining celebrity sparkle". Does combining modify celebrity and is Sparkle a noun here?

Answer (score 2):

Two qualities are combined in this person:

- Celebrity sparkle
- An unwavering message of freedom, respect and human rights

I interpret "celebrity sparkle" to mean "the positive, attractive, bright, charismatic aura that surrounds a celebrity."

Comment: (And yes, "sparkle" is being used as a noun. Or rather, "celebrity sparkle" is being used a single noun-phrase, like "salesperson experience.")